# How to fill an area bounded by grid lines and axes?

Tags: pgfplots

With `pgfplots` one can for `axis` use the options `minor xtick` and `minor ytick` together with `grid=minor` to manually produce grid lines. If one use such grid lines one may want to emphasize a certain region bounded by the grid lines and the axes by filling it with some color. Is this possible?

Here is an example to illustrate the problem. Say that I have the following

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    minor ytick={2},
    minor xtick={2},
    grid=minor
    ]
    \addplot{x};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produces

[image: Plot produced by example code]

and say that I want to emphasize upper right region that is bounded by the grid lines and the axes. How can I do this? That is, to produce something like the following:

[image: Plot with filling in region bounded by the grid lines and the axes]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a normal TikZ `\fill` command in combination with the `axis cs:` and `rel axis cs:` coordinate systems for this. Coordinates given in the form `(axis cs:2,3)` refer to the coordinate `2,3` in the data coordinate system, while `rel axis cs:1,1` refers to the upper right-hand corner of the plot canvas. In your case, you could use

```
\fill [orange!25] (axis cs:2,2) rectangle (rel axis cs:1,1);
```

before your `\addplot` command to shade the rectangular area. Note that you will want to set `axis on top`, as the coloured area would otherwise overlay the tick marks and axis lines.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    minor ytick={2},
    minor xtick={2},
    grid=minor,
    axis on top
    ]
    \fill [orange!25] (axis cs:2,2) rectangle (rel axis cs:1,1);
    \addplot{x};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```